# DataGrip Copy Table Values to Excel Error

Tags: excel, oracle, ide, datagrip

I am using **DataGrip 2020.1.5** and trying to Copy and Paste certain table values from my table (**DB is Oracle**) to an Excel file.

The portion of values I want to copy is highlighted below.

[image]

Values are pasted in a strange format on the Excel; different rows, but all on one column

[image]

Paste Format is selected as Tab-seperated (TSV) and I tried to change the settings by **Paste Format > Configure CSV Formats...** by changing **value seperator**, but it made no difference.
Column names are also pasted even if I have not ticked the **First row is header**.

I also tried this copying on both MS Excel 2010 and 2016 still the same output.

I checked about this on the web, also Jetbrains documentation but didn't find anything useful. Perhaps I am missing something here.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI; the format you are pasting is Markdown, great for pasting into gitlab tickets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, what you are trying to do is to **copy values to the clipboard** and then paste them to Excel. DataGrip has nothing to do with how Excel *pastes* values, but DataGrip can copy them in the needed way.

I assume you need TSV format for your data in the clipboard. So you need to copy your values in TSV. To do so, please choose the corresponding extractor in the drop-down:

[image]

The option you tick, *Paste format*, has nothing to do with Excel or any other third party application. It defines in what format you have values **when you are pasting into the DataGrip's spreadsheet**.